# Unsure if Google Analytics is combining metrics for URLs with segments

Tags: google-analytics

Google Analytics is recording a page called ".../form", but separately it is also reporting redirects to that page as "/form?/=test"

Under Site Content they are both listed separately.

In a case like this am I right to assume these are separate metrics that need to be added together to provide a truer picture of activity.

Or is it a case where ".../form" also includes all traffic from "/form?/=test"

EDIT: The URLs were due to redirected legacy traffic and since both were recording data in GA just trying to see about data collected to date.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that absolute URLs are needed rather than relative.

Is there somewhere to point to "http://my.domain.com/form"  instead of just "/form"?

Comment: Thanks. Changing the urls won't be an issue more asking so we can correctly interpret data collected to date.